# Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value in For In Loop

Tags: xcode, swift, for-loop, core-bluetooth, option-type

I'm trying to read a CBCharacteristic value from a found CBService, and I keep getting the error

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

My code is as follows

```
func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral!, didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService service: CBService!, error: NSError!)
{
    for characteristic in service.characteristics as! [CBCharacteristic]
    {
        peripheral.readValueForCharacteristic(characteristic)
    }
}
```

Check to ensure the CBService is not nil, and that appears to be sound. Any know the proper swift way to unpack this list?

Comment: try using if let x = service.characteristics as! [CBCharacteristic] prior to the for loop. Put the for loop in that if let.

Comment: Most of the time, you should only use `!` when you are 100% sure it won't be `nil` when you access it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks DogCoffee!

```
func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral!, didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService service: CBService!, error: NSError!)
{
    if let characteristics = service.characteristics as? [CBCharacteristic]
    {
        for characteristic in characteristics
        {
            peripheral.readValueForCharacteristic(characteristic)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can shorten that to just a `for` without the `if` (assuming you don’t want code to handle the `nil`) by using the nil-coalescing operator: `for characteristic in characteristics as? [CBCharacteristic] ?? [] { }`